# Using KeyValueGroupedDataset cogroup in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to use cogroup method on KeyValueGroupedDataset in spark. Here is a scala attempt but getting an error:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val x1 = Seq(("a", 36), ("b", 33), ("c", 40), ("a", 38), ("c", 39)).toDS
val g1 = x1.groupByKey(_._1)
val x2 = Seq(("a", "ali"), ("b", "bob"), ("c", "celine"), ("a", "amin"), ("c", "cecile")).toDS
val g2 = x2.groupByKey(_._1)
val cog = g1.cogroup(g2, (k: Long, iter1:Iterator[(String, Int)], iter2:Iterator[(String, String)]) =>  iter1);
```

But getting an error:

```
<console>:34: error: overloaded method value cogroup with alternatives:
  [U, R](other: org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset[String,U], f: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.CoGroupFunction[String,(String, Int),U,R], encoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[R])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[R] <and>
  [U, R](other: org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset[String,U])(f: (String, Iterator[(String, Int)], Iterator[U]) => TraversableOnce[R])(implicit evidence$11: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[R])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[R]
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset[String,(String, String)], (Long, Iterator[(String, Int)], Iterator[(String, String)]) => Iterator[(String, Int)])
       val cog = g1.cogroup(g2, (k: Long, iter1:Iterator[(String, Int)], iter2:Iterator[(String, String)]) =>  iter1);
```

I am getting same error in JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cogroup` you are trying to use is curried so you have to call it separately for the dataset and the function. There is also type mismatch in the key type:

```
g1.cogroup(g2)(
  (k: String, it1: Iterator[(String, Int)], it2: Iterator[(String, String)]) => 
    it1)
```

or just:

```
g1.cogroup(g2)((_, it1, _) => it1)
```

In Java, I'd use `CoGroupFunction` variant:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.CoGroupFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;

g1.cogroup(
  g2,
  (CoGroupFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple2<String, Integer>>) (key, it1, it2) -> it1,
  Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.INT()));
```

where `g1` and `g2` are `KeyValueGroupedDataset<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>` and `KeyValueGroupedDataset<String, Tuple2<String, String>>` respectively.